# Eclipse cannot find generated source files in my junit tests

Tags: eclipse, maven, mapstruct

Hi I am facing an issue with eclipse.  currently i have a java project using maven/springboot and i am using http://mapstruct.org/ libraries to generate some classes.

In my test I am declaring the generated classes (implementation) however the eclipse complain it could not be resolved to a type.

when i do a maven clean package from the terminal all the tests pass . Also i can see that the generated classes under the folder target/annotations/com/primecast/service/mapper/ , basically it is generated successfully . However when i declare an instance of the class like this from my junit test

private ProfileMapperImpl profileMapper

it shows cannot be resolved to a type. However i can find the ProfileMapperImpl class generated properly under the folder target/annotations/com/primecast/service/mapper/ 
 any idea how can i add the generated source files to my eclipse so that the eclipse wont complain . my eclipse version is eclipse photon released on 2019.

thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Have you seen [Eclipse IDE support for Mapstruct](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/ide-support/#eclipse) article? Do you have the [m2e-apt Eclipse plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/m2e-apt) installed?

Comment: @prasanth Are you able to figure the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are seeing the error in eclipse IDE at the import's section while trying to add the import statement of the implementation class. If that is the case, simply remove the import statement. The application should still be able to resolve the class without errors. That is what worked for me.